# How is Manually Coded English (MCE) different from American Sign Language (ASL)?

Tags: asl

I read about MCE in Yule’s *The Study of Language* and it raised my curiosity on how different MCE is from ASL.

Answer (score 4):

American Sign Language, like all sign languages, is a fully fledged natural human language. It is not some form of American English.

Manually Coded English uses the signs from ASL to communicate the English language. It could be considered a kind of [relexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relexification), as well as a pidgin. In practice it has as much similarity to ASL as if someone replaced every English word with one from Chinese.

Comment: i.e., MCE uses ASL words with English grammar, whereas ASL has its own grammar (such as different ways of ordering words and of forming copulas, questions, and pronouns).